# Linux-Audio-Bug: vendor/freeverb/revmodel.cpp:40: void revmodel::setrate(int): Assertion `rate <= TUNING_MAX_SAMPLE_RATE' failed

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, jack, mixxx

I'm running a debian 'testing' system:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)  
          Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-7-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64  Hardware
          Vendor: TOSHIBA
  Hardware Model: PORTEGE R30-A Firmware
         Version: Version 4.20

     GNOME Shell: 43.4
```

I installed two audio applications for jack `mixxx` and `guitarix`, which both crash during startup with almost the same ERROR-Message:

**Mixxx** *(a digital DJ system, where Wave, Ogg, FLAC and MP3 files can be
mixed on a computer for use in live performances.):*

```
mixxx: vendor/freeverb/revmodel.cpp:40: void revmodel::setrate(int): Assertion `rate <= TUNING_MAX_SAMPLE_RATE' failed.
Aborted
```

**Guitarix** *(a rock guitar amplifier for the JACK Audio Connection Kit with
one input and two outputs.):*

```
guitarix: vendor/freeverb/revmodel.cpp:40: void revmodel::setrate(int): Assertion `rate <= TUNING_MAX_SAMPLE_RATE' failed.
Aborted
```

I got jack running with 192000Hz, so I do not think the problem can be solved there:

```
JACK compiled with System V SHM support.
loading driver ..
apparent rate = 192000
creating alsa driver ... hw:TR8S,0|hw:TR8S,0|256|2|192000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 192000Hz, period = 256 frames (1.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit float little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit float little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
```

Does anyone know what ***vendor/freeverb/revmodel.cpp*** is? And how I can fix this?

*My first thought was that I had installed an incompatible plugin, but this does not seem to be the case.*

Comment: To answer what it is, functionally: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Freeverb.html

Comment: To answer why it is used in your signal chains: that path, vendor/freeverb/ appears as far as I could find, only in [amsynth](https://github.com/amsynth/amsynth). Which is an audio effect plugin thing. The fact that you get an amsynth crash when running alsa-using programs suggests you've somehow configured alsa to load it as plugin. A quick way to test that would be uninstalling amsynth and looking whether the errors go away.

Comment: @MarcusMüller **THX for your suggestion!** I removed amsynth and the ERROR-Message changed to: `lo server running on 18785 malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
Aborted` (exactly the same for both programms **mixxx/guitarix** - despite from the number of course)

Comment: End of my wits there. This looks like something really messed up memory. At this point I'd try rebooting.